# Java FX - wrong positioning of lines when drawing on GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have the following code:

```
    Button loadChunksButton = new Button("Load chunks");
    loadChunksButton.setOnAction(new LoadChunksButtonListener());

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

    gridPane.setMinSize(400, 200);
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    gridPane.setVgap(5);
    gridPane.setHgap(5);
    gridPane.add(loadChunksButton, 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(chunksListView, 0, 1);

    gridPane.add(new Line(0, 0, 250, 250), 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(new Line(0, 0, 250, 0), 1, 1);
```

Result as on below screen. Why these two lines don't start from the same point although both have specified (0, 0) as a starting point? What should I do to have absolute (0, 0) as pointed by red arrow?

[image]

Comment: Why would you draw lines in a GridPane? There are other Panes you can use to draw your lines.

Comment: I would let some other Pane cover the portions of the GridPane where I would like to draw the lines. Then I would draw the lines In that Pane.

Comment: The grid pane manages the layout of the nodes in each cell, and sets their layoutX and layoutY accordingly. It looks like the cell is configured (or defaults to) centering the nodes in the cell. So the layoutY of each line is set so that both lines are vertically centered. As @SedrickJefferson comments, you should place shape subclasses in a container that does no layout (such as a `Pane` or `Group`) if you want it to respect the literal shape coordinates.